# Mp4 file not generated in R markdown

Tags: markdown, knitr, rstudio, chunks

I set chunk option: `fig.show='animate'` in R markdown. But there is no mp4 file generated in the Figure Folder. Also no animation displayed in the knitted html. Any help or suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: did you install `ffmpeg` and is it present on `PATH`?

Comment: @Yihui  It's done now. Thanks for the reminder of installing **ffmpeg**.

Comment: so it works now? if it does, please write the answer below and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using MAC mountain lion. It works well:

Firstly you will need an MP3 encoder. FFmpeg doesn't include one, but it will use LAME, which can be [downloaded here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/).

In terminal, make a new directory and unzip the downloaded LAME. I am using the currently latest version lame-3.99.5.

```
mkdir ~/lame
cd ~/lame
tar xvzf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
```

After downloading and unpacking the source or checking it out from CVS, change to the main directory and then enter the three commands which are typically used to build open source projects:

```
cd lame-3.99.5
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then create a working directory:

```
mkdir ~/ffmpeg
cd ~/ffmpeg
```

The up-to-date version of FFmpeg generally compiles cleanly, and that is the version you usually will want:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
```

Next, configure and make

```
./configure --enable-libmp3lame --enable-shared --disable-mmx --arch=x86_64
make
sudo make install
```

Done!